# Check status of a flow hash in corda notary

Tags: state, corda, notary

How do I query the status of a flowID (or its hash) in the notary vault?(consumed/not-consumed).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you're gonna want to take a look at the NODE_CHECKPOINTS table, you can query it by flowid.

Just try it with the corda shell if you're looking just once.

Here's a breakdown of each of the tables in corda and what is contained in all of them.

https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/node-database-tables.html

If you want to do it programmatically take a look at the docs page on vault queries :

https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/api-vault-query.html

good luck

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. The flow I am using does not have any Checkpoints, and the table you mentioned comes back empty. It is the standard IOU example. Any other suggestion?